# how to create a single column content-first layout

Tags: html, css

I have a single column fixed-width layout with a header and footer that I have to make with the following in order of view.

1. header
2. navigation
3. basic content
4. basic content
5. main content
6. footer

Items 3,4 and 5 will be dynamic and expand vertically (height unknown)
Items 1,2 and 6 will be a fixed height.
Our SEO manager says he would like the 'main content' to be the first div in the body or at least above the basic contents (source view).

I have tried setting the main wrapper (around all 6 divs) to relative then absolute positioning 'main content' to the bottom.

Comment: @jacktheripper: That much is obvious, he wants his main content to be first in the HTML, but shown in the correct order (of the list) when viewing the page.

Comment: Sure but he needs a lesson in asking. In effect in that question he has said "give me codez", whereas his question should read "reposition content on page using CSS"

Comment: Can't help without seeing code really. I don't get why people want to go that far with SEO. Does it even matter how far down the html content appears? I don't think CSS is the language to do this with either. Javascript seems more appropriate.

Comment: I think I'd actually just put these in whatever order the SEO guy wants and use JavaScript to move stuff around after the page loads. Doing it in CSS will be a nightmare. Doing it with JS is ugly too, but hey, desperate times, desperate measures...

Comment: `position:absolute` within `position:relative` is your tool.

Comment: I would have said JS, but then if you turn JS off the whole page breaks. I'd say scrap the idea - HTML is hierarchical, and it provides the framework for the page, in the order it SHOULD appear!

Comment: JS is a workable idea, I wouldn't be too worried about Google executing the JS and interpreting it, more about people without JS, but your SEO might pull that one out as it was quite an important development in recent years.

Comment: Your SEO manager isn't very bright. There are other far superior methods of SEO that are much easier than changing the entire structure of your site.

Answer (score 1):

Hey u can do this easily as like this

**Css**

```
div{
    background:green;
    margin-top:10px;
    padding:20px;
    color:white;
}

#five-5{
display:none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="five"></div>
<div id="one">Header</div>
<div id="two">navigation</div>
<div id="three">basic content</div>
<div id="four">basic content</div>
<div id="six">Footer here </div>





<div id="five-5">Main Container here </div>
```

**JAVA SCRIPT**

```
document.getElementById('five').innerHTML=document.getElementById('five-5').innerHTML;
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/tk7ky/1/